# Make UITableView not scrollable and adjust height to accommodate all cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm embedding a `UITableView` inside of another `UIScrollView`. I only want the `UIScrollView` to scroll, not the `UITableView`, so I want to disable the scrolling in `UITableView`, as well as expand the `contentHeight` for the `UITableView` to accommodate all dynamic  at once.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you need that feature? You want to add more sub-view in scroll view?

Comment: I want to add a basically want to integrate subviews in the same page as a tableview, rather than having the whole view as a tableview.

Comment: so you have to expand your tableview to fit the length of that table. then adjust content size of your scroll view

Comment: After calling `reloadData` the table view should have the correct contentSize if you **don't** implement `estimatedHeight`.

Comment: if other sub-views are on the top of the table view, you can also add these sub-view in tableview: separate by sections. Section 0 contains your subview1, section 1 contains your subview2, section 2 contains your content of the tableview in question.

Comment: yeah I'm wondering if I should go this route, also has its own complications of having to customize every cell accroding to how I would display the subviews.

Comment: I'm exactly at that point right now. I started out doing the whole thing inside a single table, but having to deal with multiple sections was not so good. Now my problem is having the table view expanding the height according to the content data...

Comment: @Allen Did you get the answer or you have found the solution. If you have got the solution please let us know. I too have the same problem.

Answer (score 37):

Set tableView scrolling property to false.

**First Approach:**

1. Create a subclass for tableView and override intrinsicContentSize.

   ```
        class MyOwnTableView: UITableView {
       override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
           self.layoutIfNeeded()
           return self.contentSize
       }

       override var contentSize: CGSize {
           didSet{
               self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
           }
       }

       override func reloadData() {
           super.reloadData()
           self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
       }
   }
   ```
2. In Interface builder change the class of your tableView to MyOwnTableView (subclass UITableView).
3. Set automatic row height for the table view.

   ```
       tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0;
       tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   ```

**Second Approach:**
       1. Create a height constraint with any value for tableView and connect an IBOutlet that sets the tableView height.

2. Set the height constraint's constant to tableView.contentSize.height after reloading the data.

   ```
   self.tableViewHeight.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
   ```

Comment: excellent answer, I've seen far to many that only apply to tableViews within viewControllers, along with just plain bad answers with no explanation at all!

Comment: @JamesWolfe Thank you! :)

Comment: First Approach does not work. Second approach works fine.

Comment: Your second approach was perfect for use with Autolayout, thank you!

Comment: This worked for my use case. I had a tableview inside of a stack view which was inside of a scrollview. I needed the table to expand and show all of its content, and I needed a table because I still wanted swipe actions etc

Answer (score 12):

You need to set the `UITableView` scroll to `false`,

```
tableview.scrollEnabled = false;

tableview.frame = CGRectMake(tableview.frame.origin.x, tableview.frame.origin.y, tableview.frame.size.width, tableview.frame.size.height+(resultArray.count*HEIGHT_OF_CELL));
```

And then you can add the `UITableView` on `UIScrollView` by setting it's content size as `UITableView` height.

Comment: How about dynamic height of cells?

Comment: for dynamic height of cell you can calculate the total height in **HeightForRowAtIndexPath** method and then set the scrollView frame accordingly .

Comment: Ok, but what about lazy loading of cells? If you have 20 cells, they are all loaded at once, not by lazy loading as you scroll. They are not reused... any help?

Answer (score 12):

Set tableView size equal with contentSize.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    tableView.frame.size = tableView.contentSize
}
```

Comment: but this doesn't increase the content size of the scroll view. The content size remains fixed.

Comment: And the content is missing

Answer (score 10):

Basically, tableview's content size is all you need.

1. Set tableview scrolling to `false` because we don't want scolling behaviour.
2. Get the reference of tableview's height constraint.
3. set `tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height`

Make sure, tableview's top, bottom, leading and trailing constraint and are in-place.

Comment: For reason unknown, tableView.contentSize.height always returns 0.

Comment: make sure tableview constraints are in place properly

Comment: "Basically, tableview's content size is all you need."
This is the key point. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

1. Make your tableview frame cover all lines possible -> no scroll for table view
2. Set contentSize of your scrollview = size of your tableViews.

Comment: Also need to set tableview.bounces = NO to ensure it doesn't steal scroll focus.

Answer (score 2):

- First of all you need is to set up the `UITableView` Scrolling to `NO`
- Second, create a `height constraint` for the table view and after you call `[UITableView reloadData]` change your `height constraint`

  ```
  tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = numberOfRows * heightOfEachRow;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You could also observe the tableView's `contentSize` via KVO using Combine.

Idea: You update the height constraint of your tableView, whenever its `contentSize` changes.

I tried to achieve it using some of the solutions in this thread, but sometimes ended up with wrong `contentSize` values due to timing issues. Using KVO makes sure to catch all updates on `contentSize`.

1. Define a height constraint on your tableView
2. Make sure to disable scrolling on your tableView
3. Subscribe to changes on the KVO publisher for the tableView's `contentSize` in `viewDidLoad`
4. Assign the value of the height constraint constant to the value you receive

Code Sample for the KVO part:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    private var tokens: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.publisher(for: \.contentSize).sink { [weak self] contentSize in
            self?.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = contentSize.height
        }.store(in: &tokens)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableView is a scroll view. While you are not supposed to nest UIScrollviews, you can disable scrolling of the the table view.

Comment: i understand this, but I will need to adjust the tableview height to accomodate all cells. for instance if I have 5 cells, disabling uitableview scroll would just hide the last 2 of them.

Comment: You can do that when assigning the UITableViewCell height on the UITableView datasource callback. So, given a number of elements in the data source array, assign a height enough to fit all elements.

Answer (score 0):

While this is very simple to accomplish with a fixed-content tableview as a subview in a scrollview, what is it you are exactly trying to accomplish? Dynamic cells with fixed content above and below? Permanently displayed content with a sliding section in the center?

Perhaps a cleaner design would be using a single UITableView with a Table Header and Footer, or a Section Header an Footer leveraging the automatic behavior provided by UITableViewStyleGrouped vs UITableViewStylePlain

That said, other answers seem to form a decent solution:

```
Set scroll enabled false on table view
Set tableview content size to sum of all cell sizes
Set tableview frame to content size
Adjust scroll view frame to account for dynamic table size if necessary
Add table view to scroll view amidst other content
```

Another option for manipulating scroll behavior would be checking the tableview or scrollview in the delegate scrollView shouldStartScrolling or similar methods, as this would allow more flexibility over the UI controls