# Dynamic height TableView in a Scroll View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am designing a page having a scroll view and above it a table view(scroll disabled). For doing this I have referred answers in this question - [Make UITableView not scrollable and adjust height to accommodate all cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090104/make-uitableview-not-scrollable-and-adjust-height-to-accommodate-all-cells) ,but wasn't successful.

Hierarchy of views along with provided constraints-

**-Main View**

**-Scroll view**
pinned to all sides of main view(0,0,0,0), constraint to margins

**-Content View**

pinned to scroll view(0,0,0,0),equal width to main view,equal height to main view(priority - 250)

**-Table view inside content view**

scroll disabled,having 50 point spaces from all sides,Height(>=),bottom spacing 50(relation >=).I have put greater than equal so as to increase height dynamically.

Now when I populate my table view I use the code as

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellreuse", forIndexPath: indexPath) 
        cell.textLabel?.text = name[indexPath.row]

        tableview.frame.size = tableview.contentSize

        return cell
    }
```

So when I run my code, it increases the tableview frame but doesn't stretch the content size and it just becomes weird as my scroll view doesn't scroll to the end of the table view neither my table view obeys the auto layout constraints.

Comment: i guess you shouldn't call `tableview.frame.size = tableview.contentSize` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @aaisataev Ya correct. Check out my answer

Comment: refer these links.. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036228/uiscrollview-scrollable-content-size-ambiguity> <https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html>. Hope it helps... :)

Answer (score 56):

Just I needed to do this -

- remove the line - `tableView.frame.size = tableView.contentSize`
- Add a height constraint for table view.
- Set priority to High
- Create an outlet of the height constraint(Ctrl+Drag).
- Wherever you need to reload data of your table, set the height constraint to tableview's content height.

```
tableHeightConstraint.constant = tableview.contentSize.height
```

Comment: Its working for me, but some extra space showing at bottom of tableview ?

Comment: I used your approach, only changed the way of calculate tableviewHeight, since for me `tableview.contentSize.height` does not worked as expected. This is my way: rowHeight * numberOfRows

Comment: This is not working. @user5479794.@Isaac Bosca if you set the row height it's not autolayout.

Comment: this solution works. but for Autolayout it leaves extra space at bottom.

Comment: Found new solution if not late. Thanks to medium.com https://simaspavlos.medium.com/automatic-height-for-uitableview-into-uiscrollview-swift-8943195af10c

Answer (score 5):

1. Assign a table height. Let it be constant 0.
2. Just add below lines.

   ```
   tableView.heightConstant.constant = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
   tableView.reloadData()
   tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
   tableView.heightConstant.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
   ```

With this, you can easily achieve dynamic table height. Working on iOS 13, Swift 5.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and resolved it by doing the following:

1. Create an outlet of the height constraint for the table view with a priority of 1000

   `@IBOutlet private weak var tableViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!`
2. On `viewDidLayoutSubview` call `layoutIfNeeded` on the table view and then set the table view height constraint to the height of the content view

   ```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
       tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
       tableViewHeight.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
   }
   ```

Tested on iOS 14.1 and iOS 16.1