# UITableView inside ScrollView with infinite scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a screen which consist of two elements (`UIView` and `UITableView`). When user scrolls the screen, I want `UIView` go out of screen (top) and `UITableView` start to scroll. I'm giving a fixed height for `UIView` and fixed height for `UITableViewCells`'. In addition I'm setting bottom and top anchors  but `UITableView` doesn't show if I don't give a specific height to `UITableView`. If I give specific height for a `UITableView`, It just show some cells not all.

In addition: At first tableView is empty because Its datasource is empty. When user taps a button inside UIView, datasource fulfills and tableview refresh data.

I some posts but all of them says giving fixed height for UITableView. I don't know how to show all cells with fixed height.
Eg:
[Dynamic height TableView in a Scroll View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447238/dynamic-height-tableview-in-a-scroll-view)

**Anchors:**

```
boxView.anchor(self.view.topAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 10, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 10, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 240)
sTableView.anchor(self.boxView.bottomAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 100)
```

**How I declare UITableView:**

```
let sTableView = UITableView()
var dataSource: [SupportedService]?

let scrollView = UIScrollView()

viewDidLoad(){
sTableView.delegate = self
sTableView.dataSource = self
sTableView.register(BaseCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"supportedServicesCell")
sTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
sTableView.isScrollEnabled = false
self.scrollView.addSubview(sTableView)

self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
}
@objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton){
//Do Some Network Requests Here (Data is temp)
dataSource = DATA
sTableView.reloadData()
}
```

**TableView Functions:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let data = dataSource{
        return data.count
    }else{
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "supportedServicesCell", for: indexPath) as! BaseCell
    guard let data = dataSource else { return cell }
    cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row].title

    return cell
}
```

How I want it before scroll:

[image]

After Scroll:

[image]

Comment: What is need of nesting, I think its possible with single tableview only!!!!

Comment: Divide your tableview into two section. Or Configure table header view.
That's it.

Comment: I configure tableView header but now cells shows behind header @SPatel

Comment: can you post screen shot link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen some apps do this. But their approach is different. I will explain that approach though if it helps. Here is what they do.

- User interaction is disabled for the `tableView` in the beginning.
- Once the user swipes the screen up. The `view` is animated to hide itself by going out of the screen and the `tableView` takes up the whole screen.
- Now user interaction is again enabled on the `tableView` and it functions like a normal tableView.
- Once the user tries to scroll down even after reaching the top of the `tableView`, the `view` is animated back to the place and the parentView return to how it was originally.

Comment: If I can get the touch position and the swipe position, I can move view header as you told but I may face with a problem that UITableViews CellForRowAt function will be not called. I'll check it

Comment: You can get the touch position and and swipe position. Apple has delegates for getting those values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your approach of designing the app UI for such designs. For the current design that you are making a UITableview with headerview is the easy, nice and a better approach then embedding UIView and UITableview inside the UIScrollView.

Comment: I'll check it. I was thinking of It actually. Thank you.