# How to make UITableView fit to content's size

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` (let's call it tbl_A) inside a table view cell whose height is dynamic and set by `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. tbl_A's cell height is also dynamic, and I know tbl_A's data won't be too much. So I want tbl_A to be **scroll disabled** and its **frame.size equals its content size**. I tried to set tbl_A's frame.size.height = tbl_A.contentSize.height, unfortunately, the height is wrong.

By the way, I don't have to use `UITableView` to accomplish this task. I just want to a way to display all data. Any suggestions?

**This is the effect I want to achieve:**
[image]

Comment: I have tried every solution I can searched. @NicolasMiari I will appreciate it that if yo give me some key words.

Comment: @yon are you using objective c or swift?

Comment: @gikygik I develop with swift

Comment: Yep, the contentSize I think is related with the estimatedRowHeight. so If you record the cell height and set it after reload, I think it will work.

Answer (score 10):

Simple ;)

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return contentSize
}
```

Comment: can you explain with more details?

Comment: From the documentation: `Setting this property allows a custom view to communicate to the layout system what size it would like to be based on its content.` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize

Comment: Nice! This should be the answer

Comment: I don't think this is a very good answer at all no detail at all, I read another answer that basically offers the same solution as this one - but the person writing it went into more detail rather than just calling the solution 'simple'.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52248020/4309446

Comment: @JamesWolfe please read the documentation about `intrinsicContentSize` at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize When using auto layout and setting constraints this property sets the default size of the view. So make it return the content size of your table view and it's what you want.

Comment: I understand what you're doing - I just think it lacks explaination of any kind, maybe add that comment about documentation to your answer?

Comment: Very elegant. However you need to make sure to call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` in `contentSize` `didSet`

Answer (score 7):

Based on @Emad's answer but with the important addition to invalidate the intrinsic content size if the contentSize changes.

```
class ContentWrappingTableView: UITableView {

  override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return self.contentSize
  }

  override var contentSize: CGSize {
    didSet {
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Emad also didn't show where to put the override and left it to the reader to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

As long as scrolling is locked, you can use the following to match the tableView's layout dynamically.:

```
    let size = actionsViewController.view.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    actionsViewController.view.frame.size = size
    actionsViewController.preferredContentSize = size
```

The following presents a way to have auto layout calculate the height for you and provide you a size based on restrictions you pass in. Another way could be the following:

```
    CGFloat leftViewHeight = 0;
    if (self.isExpanded) {
        [self.lineItemLineNumberListTableViewController.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
        UITableView *tableView = self.lineItemLineNumberListTableViewController.tableView;
        CGSize tableViewContentSize = tableView.contentSize;
        leftViewHeight = tableViewContentSize.height;
    }

self.leftViewHeightConstraint.constant = leftViewHeight;
```

I had previously used the above to expand dynamically resizing cells with dynamic subviews within them. This configures a height constraint based on the content size AFTER reloading the tableView's content to ensure the content was loaded prior to adjusting the size.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add to your class reference to constraint:

```
var heightC: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

2) Disable scroll and add height constraint:

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = false
heightC = tableView.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: 20) // using PureLayout library
```

3) override viewDidLayoutSubviews of your controller:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    heightC.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
}
```

and set height constraint "constant" attribute to tableview content height.

4) on data refresh (for example when item count changes from 0 to more) just force main controller view to layout:

```
view.setNeedsLayout()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For your case you can also use scrollView.
2. In that scrollView while adding each subcell keep track of each subcell by adding each subcell's height ( take variable as referenceHeight )
3. finally set the scrollview height by calculated height(referenceHeight)

Answer (score 0):

Below is method to find tableView's content size.

```
- (CGFloat)tableViewHeightOfTable:(UITableView *)table
{
   [table layoutIfNeeded];
   return [table contentSize].height;
}
```

Make sure that you call this method after reloading your table like below code.

```
[YourTable reloadData];
YourTable.frame.size.height = [self tableViewHeightOfTable:YourTable];
```

Comment: I think this `contentSize` is calculated based on `estimatedRowHeight` which is not accurate. In the end, I used OAStackView as my container view.

Comment: Can you share your solution in detail? i am struggling for the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

In your case tableview is the best solution , you can use different uitableviewcells and sections and can load it in cellForRowAtIndexPath .